# VSTO - Office addin tooltip Icon

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

I have an Office Addin that shows some buttons on the Ribbon. Each button shows a tooltip message.

Is there a way to change the standard icon displayed below the tool-tip of such a button on the Ribbon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to change or customize that icon for developers.

Comment: @E I was wondering if you would have time to comment/suggest a possible solution to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61149776/1232087) post?