# Microsoft Office VSTO addin: How to access ribbon xml controls from ThisAddIn class

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

In my `VS2019` [VSTO project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for `WORD AddIn`, I have created button in a tab by using `Ribbon XML` as follows. And `VS2019` auto-generated the `ThisAddIn.cs` class shown below. **Question**: How can I programmatically access the button control `btnButton` of Ribbon XML from `ThisAddIn.cs` class?

**Remark**: There are some officials such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2019)  one that shows how to do it for a `Ribbon Designer`. But, I need to do it for `Ribbon XML`.

**Ribbon1.XML**:

```
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="TabID"  label="TEST">
        <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group">
          <button id="btnButton" label="Insert Text" screentip="Test button" onAction="OnTextButton" getEnabled="Get_Enabled" tag="textButtonTag"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

**ThisAddIn.cs**:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new Ribbon1();
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: "Access" in what sense? Change one of it properties or its state? Read some value from the control, etc?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I need to change the state of the button from Enable to Disable and vice versa based on a condition variable. But, from `ThisAddIn.cs`,  when I try `Ribbon1 ribbon = new Ribbpn1();  ribbon.InvalidateControl("btnButton");` it does not recognize the id `btnButton` and throws famous error: `object reference not set .......`.

Comment: The error is raised because  ribbon is null, not because the name of your control is not recognized. You need to call Invalidate() on the IRibbonUI interface. It can only be retrieved (and cached for later use) from the onLoad callback of your ribbon XML